# How to implement inheritance

Tags: delphi, oop

I have a parent class that can have 2 possible child classes:

```
  TEmailBaseAccount = class
    Connected: boolean;

    setting: TEmailAccountSettings;
    folders: TEmailAccountFolders;
    procedure Connect; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TEmailIMAPAccount = class(TEmailBaseAccount)
    IdIMAP4: TIdIMAP4;
    OpenSSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

    procedure Connect; override;
  end;

  TlEmailPOP3Account = class(TEmailBaseAccount)
    IdPOP3: TIdIPOP3;
    OpenSSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

    procedure Connect; override;
  end;
```

I'm maintaining a list of the email accounts using a generic TList:

```
  TEmailAccountList = class(TList<TEmailBaseAccount>)
    procedure SaveToStream(Stream: TStream);
    procedure LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
    constructor Create(AOwner: TObject);
    destructor Destroy;
  end;
```

and adding the email accounts to the list using the following code:

```
procedure TEmailAccountList.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);
var
  a, c: Integer;
  e: TEmailBaseAccount;
begin
  c := ReadStreamInt(Stream);
  for a := 0 to c - 1 do
  begin
    e := TEmailBaseAccount.Create(FOwnerEmailEngine);  
    e.LoadFromStream(Stream);
    Add(e);
  end;

end;

procedure TEmailAccountList.SaveToStream(Stream: TStream);
var
  a, c: Integer;
  e: TEmailBaseAccount;
begin
  c := Count;
  WriteStreamInt(Stream, c);
  for a := 0 to Count - 1 do
    Items[a].SaveToStream(Stream);
end;
```

At runtime I need to differentiate between the 2 types of child classes using something like:

```
 if account is TEmailIMAPAccount then
  ...
 else if account is TEmailPOP3Account then
  ...
```

I am sure that my original class declarations and the TList declaration is not suited to this requirement. What changes are needed in this scenario?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type declarations are absolutely fine. Your problem is presumably that when you read an item from the stream, you don't know what type it is. You cannot use is since you don't have an instance yet.

Solve that problem by writing a type code to the stream for each instance. When you read from the stream, read the type code and use that to determine which type to instantiate.

This sort of persistence streaming is so much easier using a persistence framework that emits XML, JSON, YAML etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of serializing the complete, highly implementation-specific objects, I would only write the account properties (mail account type, user credentials, server / port / security settings) to a file.

This allows to modify the implemenation without breaking existing setting file compatibility.

Also I would not even think about a `if <object> is <class> ... else if <object> is <otherclass> ...` solution. Instead, define a simple enumeration type `TAccountType = (atPOP3, atIMAP)` and then branch in a case structure depending on a account type property of the Account, or use the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: I am doing exactly this. But somewhere I am having trouble because later its not getting the correct type. I am trying to solve the problem myself right now, and will post more if the solution eludes me. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing in the Q about how each item is being persisted. Using an enumeration works fine, but you've got to put it to the file. That's the key point.

Comment: The thing is my code is so complex that its difficult to only post a section of the code and expect anyone to understand. To see the problem you need to see the entire unit which is 830 lines....

Comment: Using interface would easily avoid the 'else if', 'case' etc. several times in your code. And i agree with @DavidHeffernan, the use of xml/json would be muche easier to manipulate/store/migrate.